# Test Article creation within Rails/Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The controller redirects to the article#show once created. I included `let(:article) { create :article }` as I would otherwise get the error

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to article_path(article)

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `article' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ArticlesController::Create::ValidParams "creates an article" (./spec/controllers/article_controller_spec.rb:27)>`.
```

Anyway, I am receiving the below so it seems like creating the extra article causes this I think:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to article_path(article)

       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/articles/4> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/articles/3>.
       Expected "http://test.host/articles/4" to be === "http://test.host/articles/3".
```

**articles_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  user.confirm

  describe '#create' do
    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    context 'valid params' do
      let(:article) { create :article }

      let(:params) {
        {
          article: {
            title: 'New article title',
            body: 'New article body',
            status: 'public',
            created_at: Time.now,
            updated_at: Time.now,
            user:
          },
        }
      }
      it 'creates an article' do
        # debugger
        post :create, params: params
        expect(response).to redirect_to article_path(article)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**articles_controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  # Rails ACTIVERECORD method :include which loads associative records in
  # advance and limits the number of SQL queries made to the DB.
  # To improve performance.
  def home
    @user = User.includes(:articles, :comments)
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @article.comments.order(updated_at: :desc)
    @article.update(views: @article.views + 1)

    mark_notifications_as_read
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user = current_user

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article created successfully'
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article updated successfully'
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path, status: :see_other, notice: 'Article deleted successfully'
  end

  # All private methods ensure only the class they're initialized in can access the method
  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :status)
  end

  def mark_notifications_as_read
    return unless current_user

    notifications_to_mark_as_read = @article.notifications_as_article.where(recipient: current_user)
    notifications_to_mark_as_read.update_all(read_at: Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

**factories/article**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :article do
    title { Faker::Lorem.words(number: 2) }
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs }
    created_at { Faker::Time.between(from: DateTime.now - 1, to: DateTime.now) }
    updated_at { Faker::Time.between(from: DateTime.now - 1, to: DateTime.now) }
    status { 'public' }
    association :user, factory: :user
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'articles#home'
  get 'search', to: 'search#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  # allows for chained url routes
  # eg. /posts/1/comments/4
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

**rails routes**

```
                articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                                                               articles#index
                         POST   /articles(.:format)                                                                               articles#create
             new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                                                           articles#new
            edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                      articles#edit
                 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#show
                         PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#update
                         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#update
                         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#destroy
```

Comment: You are creating a NEW article (that's what you are testing anyway), you need get that article, not an existing one.  After your post, do something like ```article = Article.last```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second error

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to article_path(article)

   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/articles/4> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/articles/3>.
   Expected "http://test.host/articles/4" to be === "http://test.host/articles/3".
```

The problem is the *expect* block. Since you are doing a POST request to create a new record, the expectation should check that there's an increase in the record count not being redirected to another record, the one created on the *let* block.

I would recommed changing your test to something like this:

```
  it 'creates an article' do
    expect { post :create, params: }.to change { Article.count }.by(1)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
```